# copy file content contain integer data from one file to another

Tags: java

I have created one file named `random.txt`.

My job is to take inputs from that file, storing it into another file using `ObjectOutputStream`.

I have written code for that but I am getting Following Error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.io.EOFException
    at java.io.DataInputStream.readInt(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream$BlockDataInputStream.readInt(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readInt(Unknown Source)
    at SortingNumberFile.main(SortingNumberFile.java:13)
```

My Code is:

```
import java.util.*; 
import java.io.*;

public class SortingNumberFile {
  public static void main(String []args) throws IOException {
    FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream("D:\\Programs\\AJP\\random.txt");
    ObjectInputStream ois = new ObjectInputStream(fis);
    File f = new File("D:\\Programs\\AJP\\sort.txt");
    FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(f);
    ObjectOutputStream oos = new ObjectOutputStream(fos);
    int i;

    while ((i=ois.readInt())!=-1) {
      oos.writeInt(i);
      System.out.println(i);
    }

    fis.close();
    ois.close();
    fos.close();
    oos.close();

    System.out.println("Done !!!");
  }
}
```

Comment: Using an Object Output stream doesn't seem good in this case, but I don't understand your intentions either. What are you trying to do with it?

Comment: Please [edit] your question and include a short sample of your file.

Answer (score 2):

You'd better use `try with resources` in Java 7 or above to remove lots of exception handling burdens. One of the solutions can be:

```
    try (Scanner scanner = new Scanner(new File(inputPath));
         BufferedWriter bufferedWriter = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(outputPath))) {
         while (scanner.hasNextInt()) {
            int a = scanner.nextInt();
            bufferedWriter.write(String.valueOf(a) + "\n"); 
            // seems you're using Windows, so it should be replace with \r\n perhaps;
            System.out.println(a);
        }
    }
    System.out.println("Done !!!");
```

Test Data (same input format and output format):

```
1
2
3
4
```